# Authorize.net is upgrading to CyberSource SCA. Will our payment gateway still work?

Tags: payment-processor, authorize.net

Auth.net tell us that they are upgrading our account to CyberSource and that this entails moving to Strong Customer Authentication (SCA).

Looking at their information on this, https://www.cybersource.com/en-EMEA/psd2/upgrade/, it seems likely this will have substantial impact on the code of the Auth.net payment processor. I'm not at all sure about this... but wanting to ask the question just to be sure!

I think Auth.net plan to make this change in the next month or two, so if changes to code are necessary then this will need to take place soon!

I've phoned Auth.net support, but they are very hazy about whether code changes will be required. They 'think' 'maybe not'... Hmmm!

They said that they are merging with CyberSource and that they are therefore merging the best of their software with the best of CyberSource's software. Furthermore, they said they are receiving developers bit by bit, and currently the information is trickling out to them day by day.

We are on civicrm and drupal latest, based in the UK.

Does anyone have any details about this?

Comment: There was some discussion for Stripe and PayPal at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/41. Maybe add a comment there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We updated the AuthorizeNet processor here: https://github.com/mattwire/com.donordepot.authnetecheck for both echeck and credit card.

However, it looks like AuthNet will not be supporting SCA (so you'll be fine for non EU payments) but will need to switch to Cybersource to accept EU payments via credit card.  It looks like Cybersource is supported by the Omnipay processor https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor

Comment: Yes - CyberSource does work fine with OmniPay

Comment: Thanks everyone, for your help!

Comment: @themak Can you add an answer which explains the steps of configuring omnipay CyberSource in civicrm?